# Dynamic div height on load based on viewport height (Kendo UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

The following code block basically handles both load and resize event just fine in a normal setup but with the front-end framework we are using (Kendo UI), the targeted div height is not set property when page gets first loaded.

```
var resizeGrid = function() {
    var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
    var search = $("#something").outerHeight();
    $(".k-grid-content").height(viewportHeight - (400 - search));
};
$(window).resize(function() {
    resizeGrid();
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).trigger("resize");
});
```

I have a demo here that replicates the same setup using Kendo UI.

[JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/jatotojo/5/edit)

You will notice the grid height changes dynamically when the browser screen height
changes but not when the page is first loaded. How should I go about this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the kendoGrid ajax request completes after the page load. You need to add this to the kendoGrid `dataBound` method, so that it resizes the grid after the content is loaded.

```
dataBound: function(e) {
  resizeGrid();
},
```

See jsBin http://jsbin.com/jatotojo/8/edit

Comment: Thanks. Although we decided to go with different direction, your solution exactly addressed my issue. Would you please look into my new thread which is basically from the same issue but with different approach by setting the inside content height 100%. [Setting Kendo UI grid height 100% of wrapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622241/setting-kendo-ui-grid-height-100-of-wrapper)