# How to extend the height of a Kendo-UI grid to 100% in an AngularJS 1.x way?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, height, kendo-grid

I recently ran into the problem that I needed a Kendo UI Grid widget that has its height set to 100% of the surrounding `<div>`. I tried to apply some basic CSS on my grid - without success:

```css
html, body {
    height:100%;
}
.expand-vertical {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%
}
```

```xml
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController as vm" class="expand-vertical">
    <kendo-grid k-options="vm.gridOptions" class="expand-vertical"></kendo-grid>
</div>
```

As you can see in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spontifixus/btjgzkup/4/) this works fine - as long as one does not resize the window:

[image]

I found a solution how to achieve this using jQuery [in an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22630544/1521227) to a [somewhat similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22622241/1521227), this question however *does not cover the approach to take when using angular*.

I could place that code into my controller, but I am not sure whether that's the correct place to manipulate the DOM at all. How can I achieve the desired behavior in an elegant AngularJS way?

Answer (score 4):

The correct place in AngularJS 1.x to "hide" code manipulating the DOM is a [directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). To quote the AngularJS docs:

> At a high level, directives are markers on a DOM element (such as an attribute, element name, comment or CSS class) that tell AngularJS's HTML compiler ($compile) to attach a specified behavior to that DOM element or even transform the DOM element and its children.

Thus you could create your own directive to attach the desired resizing behavior to your grid:

```js
// Define the directive and inject the angularJS reference
// to the $window object.
app.directive('expandKGrid', ['$window', function ($window) {

    // Define the directive, but restrict its usage to 
    var directive = {
        link: link,           // The function attaching the behavior
        restrict: 'A',        // Restrict directive to be used only as attribute
        require: 'kendoGrid', // Ensure the directive is set on a <kendo-grid> element
    };
    return directive;


    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var gridElement = $(element);

        // Attach an eventHandler to the resize event of the
        // window to resize the data area of the grid accordingly
        $($window).resize(function () {
            // Get the element wrapping the data
            var dataElement = gridElement.find('.k-grid-content');
            // Get all other elements (headers, footers, etc...)
            var nonDataElements = gridElement.children().not('.k-grid-content');
            // Get the height of the whole grid without any borders or margins
            var currentGridHeight = gridElement.innerHeight();
            // Calculate and set the height for the data area, which
            // is the height of the whole grid less the height taken
            // by all non-data content.
            var nonDataElementsHeight = 0;
            nonDataElements.each(function () {
                nonDataElementsHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
            });
            dataElement.height(currentGridHeight - nonDataElementsHeight);
        });
    }
}]);
```

Finally apply this directive to your grid:

```xml
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="demoController as vm" class="expand-vertical">
    <kendo-grid k-options="vm.gridOptions" expand-k-grid class="expand-vertical">
    </kendo-grid>
</div>
```

All of this - the combination of the CSS you already provided together with the AngularJS directive ensures that the grid always has a height of 100% of its surrounding container, even when the window gets resized:

[image]

You can see this in action in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spontifixus/btjgzkup/).

Comment: I know this post is old but; consider using the built in resize function, also be sure to clean up the events when your directive is destroyed.